# MongoDB - fast & accurate k-NN

Tags: postgis, mongodb, knn

We have been testing the effectiveness of the *k*-NN query in MongoDB and Postgis on [New Year City's taxi dataset](https://www1.nyc.gov/site/tlc/about/tlc-trip-record-data.page) on two aspects: run-time and accuracy. The staggering outcome is that MongoDB detects the *k*-NN of a given point ***instantly*** regardless the value of *k* (even for *k*=1 million).

In addition, we have relied on the Haversine and Vincenty functions to evaluate the accuracy and the detected neighbours. The neighbours detected by MongoDB are also more closer to the query point. In other words, Postgis missed some of the closer points.

How could MongoDB be super-fast (i.e. O(1)) and and also be accurate?

I seek scientific evidence.

Code is available openly avaiable on [Github](https://github.com/bugracoskun/K-NN).

MongoDB Query

```
db.nyc2015.find( {
geometry_pk: {
$nearSphere: {
$geometry: {
type: "Point",
coordinates: [point_lon, point_lat] } } } }
).limit(k)
```

Postgres Query

```
select id
from trips
order by l_pickup <->
(select l_pickup
from trips
where id = point_ID)
limit k
```

Comment: interesting; I don't know much about the underlying NoSQL concepts of MongoDB, but it seems quite possible (I wouldn't wonder, actually) that the in-memory processing of simple JSON objects is indeed more performant. I wonder how higher dimensional geometries (> *Point*) perform. three things: 1) the `nearSphere` function is a proximity search with distance order; a similar approach with `ST_DWithin` or `&&` to limit the *KNN* might boost execution. 2) pass a literal constant to the `<->` operator instead of a subquery result to enable *index only scans* (compare `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`).

Comment: still 2) an *index only scan* should beat a proximity pre-selection (as in 1) ), though 3) use an indexed *geography* column to actually get spherical (not spheroidal) distance measures. the *geometry* type treats LonLat also as planar

Comment: Interesting question. I have worked a bit with MongoDB in the past, but, abandoned it due its fairly limited spatial functionality and lack of spatial reference systems beyond lat/lon. If I recall correctly,  under the hood it uses a form of indexing based on geohashing. I can imagine it might be quite fast for this kind of query. Assuming you have written the query correctly, it is not possible (well, extraordinarily unlikely) that Postgis is not returning the results in the correct order. This is an interesting question, but, I am not sure I have the time available right now to do it justice

Comment: While I am very comfortable with Python, it would be helpful if you could provide a single Postgres query that you have run, where you claim it is missing some points, and I will have a go at answering that part of the question. I am happy to load the NYC taxi dataset, and run Postgres queries, but, I really don't have time for the MongoDB part right now.

Comment: Please provide a code snippet that illustrates what you have tried and where you are stuck as formatted text within your question body.

Answer (score 4):

It's tricky to tell what might be slowing things down. But I have a few suspicions from looking at the code.

- Mongodb may well be serving from RAM if the records fit into memory. Or it may have cached results from previous runs. Try restarting mongod before each run to see if this is a factor.
- The unpacking of objects returned from postgres is being done in python; in Mongo, you're not needing to do this. If you have thousands or millions of rows, this will all add up. You could maybe try using the psycopg2 [DictCursor class](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#dictionary-like-cursor) to return each row as a dict rather than a tuple.
- Did you remember to set up spatial indexes on the postgres tables? (I didn't see them in your .sql file). Try running your queries directly on a postgres client (ideally with an EXPLAIN PLAN) to see if your code is using the spatial indexes.

EDIT: As per [the instructions on K-NN with postgis](https://postgis.net/docs/geometry_distance_knn.html), it's important to avoid using CTEs and to make sure you use a constant, rather than a join or subquery.

For example, using an OSM database with about 500K points

This query took 3 seconds:-

```
with b as (
    select * from planet_osm_point
)
select 
    b.osm_id, st_asewkt(b.way), st_geomFromEWKT('SRID=4326;POINT(-3.15 55.85)') <-> b.way as dist
from b
order by
    st_geomFromEWKT('SRID=4326;POINT(-3.15 55.85)') <-> b.way
limit 1000;
```

This functionally identical one took 139ms, a 20x speedup.

```
select 
    planet_osm_point.osm_id, 
    st_asewkt(planet_osm_point.way), 
    st_geomFromEWKT('SRID=4326;POINT(-3.15 55.85)') <-> planet_osm_point.way as dist
from 
    planet_osm_point
order by
    st_geomFromEWKT('SRID=4326;POINT(-3.15 55.85)') <-> planet_osm_point.way
limit 1000;
```

It may well be faster to do two queries - one to look up the target geometry, then prepare a second query with a constant geometry based on its location.

Comment: This is a very good answer. There are often other ways to speed up K-NN queries using <-> with the use of DWithin, though, this does require having a known radius limit. As you say, the structure of MongoDB is so different to Postgres, it is very hard to realistically compare timings, and without knowing which points from Postgis were supposedly incorrectly not returned, impossible to meaningfully constrast.

Comment: one thing: those two queries perform differently because the CTE is basically unoptimizable by the planner, meaning that, in the first query, all 500k rows actually have to be fetched before processing. the important part (and what the docs warn about) is the other, static geometry that has to be a constant (literal) to enable *index only scans*. but index *supported* scans are still possible even when that geometry is psssed in via selection (or OP would still be waiting for results...). I found that, in the optimal setting, a `ST_DWithin` pre-filter might even slow things down a little.